# Google Dart: Application(Game) becomes slow after a while

Tags: html, performance, html5-canvas, dart

I've written a simple game (Paratrooper) in Dart. After 2 minutes of playing, the game becomes too slow. Here are a few observations:

1. 3 processes of Chrome are created, each consuming > 80 MB
2. My game is running on 32-bit hardware, 4GB RAM, Dual Core
3. At any point, less than 30 objects are drawn onto canvas
4. I use Dart:Timer to call a method every 8 ms

Any suggestions will be helpful.

Thanks,
Uday

Comment: Open the console and use the Timeline and Profile features to try to find the reason for causing this slow down. Also, is this on Dartium or Chrome (compiled to JavaScript)?

Comment: Thanks for the tip Kai.
I'm using Dartium.
Are Timeline and Profile plugins that I can use on windows? I'm using Dartium on windows, as of now.

Comment: Just hit F12 and go to the tabs.

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to tell without the code, however try to use this function instead of a Timer, I've been using it and the game don't lag(on chromium) drawing +100 elements at once.

```
window.animationFrame.then(update);
void update(){
   //Your refresh code here, like clean the context, redraw visual elements.
   window.animationFrame.then(update);
}
```